# Is there a way to add graphics to Show and keep the image "still"?

Tags: graphics

Let's say I'm writing a PDF presentation such that on slide 1, I want to show a sphere, and on slide 2 I want to continue showing the same sphere plus a point. I could draw these in Mathematica using

```
sphere1 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]];
point1 = Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 2}]];
```

and then generate two consecutive graphics, using

```
g1 = Show[sphere1]
g2 = Show[sphere1, point1]
```

My problem is that from g1 to g2, the point of view changes, so it looks like the presentation is "shaking" as you move from slide to slide.

Of course in this example, you need more room for the point because it is far from the sphere, so it makes sense.

But my question is this: if I know beforehand all the graphics that I want to include in my Show command, is there a way to **keep the image still**, i.e., so that the point of view is always the same as the graphics are added one by one?

I tried as a little "hack" to make some graphics transparent with Opacity[0], but then they make white shadows on the graphics below them, so they're not really invisible.

Comment: Give all of the images the same `PlotRange`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you! I knew there had to be a simple solution, but I didn't know PlotRange worked within Graphics3D as well. If you want to post that as a solution I'll accept it.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem, following Bob Hanlon's suggestion, is to specify the **PlotRange** directly in the **Show** command, so that Mathematica holds it still no matter what graphics are inserted or removed.